# Every field has an algebraic closure proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

Below is the proof in Fraleigh.
[image: Fraleigh proof]

The part that I don't understand is the construction of set $A$. What does "every possible zero of any $f(x)$" mean? When the textbook talked about "zeros", they are always defined in a larger field, now there is no such single extension fields (at least not proved yet), how should I make sense of such a set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $A$ is not a field it is just a sufficiently large set. For example one could define it slightly more formally as $A = \bigcup \{(f,i)\,|\, f \in F[x];i \in \{0,...,\text{degree}(f)-1\}\}$. Once again for example one could define $\Omega = P(A) \cup F$ (where $P(A)$ denotes the power set of $A$). The idea is that we want a set sufficiently large so that for each algebraic extension we can construct an isomorphic algebraic extension whose underlying set is a subset of this large set.

Comment: Later he formed a set of all algebraic extensions (that are subsets of $\Omega$) that is partially ordered under subfield inclusion. So is it the case that there are multiplication and addition defined on set $A$? If so, why can't the definitions (which should agree with the extentions of $F$) contradict? If not, how is subfield inclusion defined?